# Expand new editor type in biblatex-chicago bibliography

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bibkey,
   editor = {Jeremiah Bullfrog},
   editora = {Peter Rabbit},
   editoratype = {serieseditor},
   title = {Title of the Book},
   location = {Somewhere},
   publisher = {Babylon Press},
   year = {2001}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{cbyserieseditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  cbyserieseditor = {series editor},
}

\begin{document}
  Typical line.\autocite[99]{bibkey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

A new key and string combination for series editor has been created, which works fine in the citation. However, in the bibliography, the key name seems to be printed instead:

[image: Incorrect editor type in bibliography]

I presume this is because another bibliography string must be defined, but I am at a loss to figure out what it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`byserieseditor` seems to work:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bibkey,
   editor = {Jeremiah Bullfrog},
   editora = {Peter Rabbit},
   editoratype = {serieseditor},
   title = {Title of the Book},
   location = {Somewhere},
   publisher = {Babylon Press},
   year = {2001}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{cbyserieseditor}
\NewBibliographyString{byserieseditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  cbyserieseditor = {series editor},
  byserieseditor = {series editor}
}

\begin{document}
  Typical line.\autocite[99]{bibkey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank-you, it does indeed. I did scour the documentation (and similar queries here) but to no avail; I found only comments on the cby* string addition and nothing to indicate what the various string structures ought to be.

Comment: I made a lucky guess. I decided that "c" is for citation...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, so I tried bby*, for bibliography, no luck :)